# Pick a specific part from json string

Tags: javascript, php, json, curl

I'm trying to connect my checkout page with payment gateway. For this I'm using php Curl and generating response. the response contains various details of payment but I need to pick up only url which is stored in "longurl" for redirection.

> `{ "success": true, "payment_request": { "id":
>   "9f999fc8407d473c8c8f910e8398a527", "phone": "+917894561230", "email":
>   "foo@example.com", "buyer_name": "", "amount": "798.00", "purpose":
>   "ad", "status": "Pending", "send_sms": true, "send_email": true,
>   "sms_status": "Pending", "email_status": "Pending", "shorturl": null,
>   "longurl":
>   "https://www.instamojo.com/@mghj/9f999fc8407d473c8c8f910e8398a527",
>   "webhook":
>   "http://www.example.com/webhook/", "created_at":
>   "2016-07-20T16:53:12.349Z", "modified_at": "2016-07-20T16:53:12.349Z",
>   "allow_repeated_payments": false }`

```
<?php
$payer_name = $_POST['name'];
$amt = $_POST['net_amt'];
$amt = (int)$amt;
$payer_email = $_POST['email'];
$payer_no = $_POST['mobno'];
$payer_no = (int)$payer_no;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.instamojo.com/api/1.1/payment-requests/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array("X-Api-Key:39ae74945179d56e3",
                  "X-Auth-Token:21f3446b20aab6"));
$payload = Array(
    'purpose' => 'ad',
    'amount' => $amt,
    'phone' => $payer_no,
    'buyer_name' => $payer_name,
    'redirect_url' => 'http://www.example.com/redirect/',
    'send_email' => true,
    'webhook' => 'http://www.example.com/webhook/',
    'send_sms' => true,
    'email' => 'foo@example.com',
    'allow_repeated_payments' => false
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($payload));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: you don't deal with json directly. it's a transport format. you decode that json to a native data structure, and then deal with that structure like any other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, decode it to array. then access it.

```
$result = json_decode($response,true);

echo $result['payment_request']['longurl'];
```

Comment: when I'm trying to open the link in new window it is been blocked as popup can you please suggest me with method to avoid this @Mojtaba
 `echo "<script>"; $url1 = $result['payment_request']['longurl']; echo "window.open('$url1','_blank');"; echo "</script>"; `

Comment: @Aditya, You can't control the popup blocker of the browser. The alternate is using javascript popups like jquery modal. The native popup could be blocked by browsers